# Reading in specific fields from related model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've this simple relationship setup and working, but now I need to modify it and am running into an issue. It was "get the names of products related to the current user," but now it is "get the names, start dates, and ending dates of products related to the current user."

For the former, I was getting it with the following:

```
# models.py
class Products(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=16)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    start_date= models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)  
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserToProduct')
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Products'

class UserToProduct(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_product', db_column='user_id', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='product', db_column='product_id', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.product

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'User_to_Product'
        unique_together = ('user', 'product')
        ordering = ['-product']
```

And with the following serializers:

```
# serializers.py
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.CharField()
    product_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = [
            'product_id',
            'product'
        ]

class GetHomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    product_list = ProductListSerializer(required=False, many=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data:
            data['product_list'] = UserToProduct.objects.filter(user=data['id']).prefetch_related('product').filter(product__stage='active')
            return data
```

Now I'm trying to modify my query to something like the following:

```
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.CharField()
    product_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    start_date = serializers.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserToProduct
        fields = [
            'product_id',
            'product',
            'start_date'
        ]

... #stuff in between

data['product_list'] = UserToProduct.objects.filter(user=data['id']).prefetch_related('product').filter(product__stage='active').values('product_id', 'product', 'product__start_date')
```

And adding that field to the `ProductListSerializer`. I get the error:

```
KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `start_date` on serializer `ProductListSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'start_date'."
```

Also tried the following:

```
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id= serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    start_date = serializers.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'start_date'
        ]

... #stuff in between

data['product_list'] = UserToProduct.objects.filter(user=data['id']).prefetch_related('product').filter(product__stage='active').values('product__id', 'product__name', 'product__start_date')
```

This results in the same error, with the `id` being the field with an error.

Tried replacing `values()` with `.select_related(products__product)` and that just results in:

```
Choices are: user, product
```

Tried `.select_related(product)` and it says:

```
Original exception text was: 'UserToProduct' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

**What gives here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`source`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) parameter to specify the nested relationship as,

```
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.CharField()
    product_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    start_date = serializers.DateField(source='product.start_date') # chage is here <<<<<

    class Meta:
        model = UserToProduct
        fields = [
            'product_id',
            'product',
            'start_date'
        ]
```

Moreover, your **`validate()`** method is not good, it's not the way it should be. The validate method should `raise` some `ValidationError` if some particular condidtion not met.
**Example:**

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    age = serializers.IntegerField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['age']:  # if age is there
            if attrs['age'] < 18:  # validation check for 
                raise serializers.ValidationError("You are under 18. Not allowed")
        return attrs

    def validate_age(self, age):
        if age < 18:  # validation check for 
            raise serializers.ValidationError("You are under 18. Not allowed")
        return age
```

Comment: It is giving me a `'UserToProduct' object has no attribute 'product__start_date'` like it is looking for the for that to be a field name in `UserToProduct`.